# Повышение рейтинга всем вопросам подряд

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Давно заметил тенденцию, что абсолютно все вопросы (с тегом `android`) получают +1 к рейтингу почти сразу же после создания. При чем не имеет значения, хороший это вопрос, или плохой. Плюсы получают даже очевидные дубликаты вопросов.

В связи с чем у меня возник вопрос, а не является ли это вредительством? Деятельностью, направленной на введение пользователей в заблуждение относительно реальной полезности вопроса?
Другими словами, кто-то *плюсует* все вопросы подряд. Зачем такое делать?

Comment: Набивает голоса для баджа.

Comment: @Suvitruf надо найти его и подсказать, что минусы (бесплатные для вопросов!) тоже учитываются как голоса.

Answer (score 9):

У нас **десятки тысяч** посещений в день, и около **ста** новых вопросов в день. А еще [особая шляпа](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/vote-early-vote-often):

> **Vote Early, Vote Often**
>
> проголосуйте суммарно 250 раз за семь последовательных дней по UTC

Ничего удивительного в массовом голосовании в таких условиях.

Comment: Vote Early, Vote Blind!